# Can you upload .npy files to h2o3 without converting them first

Tags: h2o

We have our data stored as .npy files. One for the features and the other for all the targets we want to impute (we plan on just selecting one target column at a time to be trained). It doesn't look like .npy is supported (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html#supported-file-formats) in h2o, but I was wondering if there was a workaround to directly import .npy files, without having to convert them to .csv and basically having to double our storage space.

When I uploaded the .npy as pandas dataframes, I would get an error at ncols = training_frame.ncols, saying DataFrame object has no attribute 'ncols'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert them (a similar situation for .rdata files for R users). (It would be nice if binary files like that were supported, so you could try a feature request.)

You don't strictly need to double your storage space: you could load each npy file into the Python client, then use:

```
d = h2o.H2OFrame(my_npy)
```

(Last time I checked the source, this will actually save to a temporary csv file, then import that file, then delete the temporary file.)

Whether that step adds any significant time to your overall model training depends on the size of the data, if a multi-node cluster, and if your client is on the cluster, or other side of the world. But, for non-trivial models, the training time is always at least an order of magnitude more than loading data, so not worth too much effort trying to speed it up.

Comment: Thanks Darren, h2o.H2OFrame() worked awesome. I'll probably put in a feature request for uploading binary files directly still.